# Change ampersand to a question mark

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ajax=0 [L]
```

Is it possible for me to change the `&` in the below URL to a `?`? Currently I have to use the ampersand for php to grab the `2`. For beautification, can I get it to use a `?` because right now I can't get php to get the `2` with the question mark.

`http://example.com/develop/game&id=2`
OR
`http://example.com/develop/game&id=2&var2=123&var3=abc`

So the above would then look like this:

`http://example.com/develop/game?id=2`
OR
`http://example.com/develop/game?id=2&var2=123&var3=abc`

Comment: That... is one broken-ass PHP script.

Comment: Really not clear what you need here. You are just using `[L]` so beautification shouldn't be an issue (the user's address bar doesn't change). On the PHP side, `index.php?page=$1&action=$2&ajax=0` results in `$_GET['page'] == ($1) and `$_GET['action'] == ($2)` and `$_GET['ajax'] == 0`.  It isn't clear what you mean by needing to use `?`.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish, is just using a `?` instead of `&` in the URL.